# Determining whether a language $L_{a}$ is recursively enumerable

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, computability

I'm trying to determine whether a language $L_{a}$ is recursively enumerable, but first I'm having trouble deciphering the definition $L_{a}$ given the following question:

Given an recursively enumerable language $L$, we can define $L_{a} = \{ x : \exists\langle M\rangle \in L \text{ such that } x \in L(M)\}$. Prove $L_{a}$ is recursively enumerable.

I understand it as the language $L_{a}$ is searching for a Turing Machine encoding $\langle M \rangle$ that exists in $L$, but I'm not sure this is correct.

Furthermore, for this problem would it be easier to create and algorithm that enumerates $L_{a}$ or to prove it's recursively enumerable through some sort of contradiction?

Comment: Since $L\in RE$, you can think of it as a list of (encodings of) Turing Machines, that can be printed out in some order, such that every TM is eventually printed out. Then, the question is, given a string $x$, will one of these machines in $L$ accept $x$. Can you see how to build a TM that will check this?

Comment: Please don't [double post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/212668). (Duplicate is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4071524/determining-whether-a-language-l-a-is-recursively-enumerable)